# Sudoers blacklist

Tags: sudo, sudoedit

We need to add few users to the sudoers file on Linux. They should be able to to anything root can except the following:

- Should not modify, read, delete `/nfsshare/config`
- Should not modify, read, delete `/etc/passwd`
- Should not mount anything
- Should not change root password
- Should not edit `/etc/sudoers` or run `visudo` to add other users

Is this possible?

Comment: No, it is not .

Comment: A whitelist is possible.

Answer (score 25):

I am, basically, in agreement with Wissam Al-Roujoulah on this.

> We need to add few users to the sudoers file

Do you, **really** need to do this? Maybe there are other ways, using `acl` or regular UNIX permissions.

As Wissam Al-Roujoulah has already pointed out, trying to "blacklist" certain commands, is in reality a really bad idea (read below from `man sudoers`, emphasis mine):

```
Note, however, that using a ‘!’ in conjunction with the built-in
 ALL alias to allow a user to run “all but a few” commands rarely
 works as intended
```

Instead you can specify a "whitelist", e.g. the actual commands the users are **allowed** to run. Something like this:

```
user1 ALL=/sbin/shutdown
```

The above will allow `user1` to shut down. You can add more commands in a comma separated list.

Read more about this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/735172/how-to-prevent-sudo-users-from-running-specific-commands).

Comment: To illustrate how pointless it is to try to disable specific commands: you can try to block `shutdown`, but if you forget to block similar functionality in `init`/`systemctl`(/`reboot`) or still allow `sudo su -` or `sudo sh` or `sudo script_that_invokes_shutdown.sh` by omission, you really haven't accomplished anything.

Comment: @Rhymoid: Don't forget `sudo gcc my-evil-file.c; sudo a.out`.  Lather, rinse, repeat with Python, Perl, Ruby, Bash, etc.

Comment: My current favorite: if "command" is blacklisted, just add another `sudo` and it'll work: `sudo sudo command`.

Answer (score 13):

I guess that is almost impossible, because you have to prevent the user from using any editor, even though that wouldn't prevent him because he can install another one or move the binary to any other location and use it.

The main point you can't add user to `sudoers` and give him all permission but some.

You have to do it in the Opposite way.

Answer (score 4):

`su`/`sudo` access is opt-in, not opt-out. Once they are able to get a root shell they can circumvent any other protections you put in place. If they have specific things that need to be run and managing the `sudoers` file is too complicated (which is probably the best approach to take in general), consider writing small single-purpose binaries that launch the thing and then set the `setuid` flag on them instead.

Comment: Don't write custom binaries, use the option of sudo to restrict the user to a certain command

Comment: The reason I suggested custom binaries is because you can't set a shell script setuid, and managing the permissions within the sudoers file can be pretty perilous on its own. But point well taken - I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at using SELinux? Which distribution are you using?

It might be possible to create a new SELinux user and give him only the needed privileges(access to roles). Tt will be an opt-in, so you will need to list everything that the user needs to do.