# Restrict certain command options

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

How can I restrict a user from executing `sudo -su`? I.e., disable this `-su` option for sudo allowed users.

Comment: You can not. `sudo` user can run anything as user root, why is there a need to do this anyways? You should reconsider your security concept.

Comment: You  can always rename or delete the `sudo` binary. I think you need to describe your problem a lot better with many more details.

Comment: @RoVo this is not true. `sudo` allows for quite fine grained management. Of course nothing sensible would prevent a user from typing `sudo -su` in a shell.

Comment: While you are able to restrict what `sudo` is allowed to do in `sudoers` file, `sudo` users can change that to whatevery they like. So technically you might be right, but practically you're not.

Comment: @RoVo: They can only chage it if they can edit the file as root, but that doesn't need to be the case. You could user 1000 allow to run `/bin/bash` as user 1001. User 1000 will not be able to change the sudoers file.

Comment: I don't get it, If the user has `sudo` rights, how will you prevent him from editing `sudoers` file ?

Comment: @RoVO: Others-executable permissions on the  binary are enough to use `sudo`. You do not need to own neither binary nor configuration files. You do not need to be a member of the group(s) sudo and its configuration files belong to. You needn't configure `sudo` to grant users permissions to edit its configuration files. I have no idea what "`sudo` rights" are, but it sounds like more than is required.

Comment: @RoVo, there's no such thing as `sudo` rights. There's a list of rules in `sudoers` that determine what commands some users can run in the name of what other users.

Comment: Okay, true, but OP asks for "*sudo allowed users*", so I assume he means users in `sudo` group that **should** be allowed to run any command as root with `sudo` (that is what I mean by *sudo rights* which is technically not the correct term) but not `sudo su`. So they could also run `sudo visudo` to remove restrictions.

Comment: @RoVo, the OP asks about `sudo -su`, either a typo and they  meant `sudo  su`, or they  ask about the `-s` and `-u` options.

Comment: @AVS If you are trying to prevent users which are allowed to execute any command as root using `sudo` from being able to "run a shell as another user" (as `sudo -su` suggests), then the answer is that it's a bad idea. See, for instance, [Sudoers blacklist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/329405/315749). It would be better if you could restate your requirements in terms of "how can I allow some users to only execute these commands as root/as another user?".

Comment: Thats fine i have gone through many answers available on stack exchange that whitelisting is a best practice. What i want is to replace a command # sudo -su someuser with some other command globally.